# Confusing ErrorAction behavior when using PSSession

Tags: powershell, error-handling, exchange-server

I'm writing a script that will be run **remotely** against my mail server using something similar to:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
$session = New-PSSession `
    -ConnectionUri http://mailserver/PowerShell/ `
    -Authentication Kerberos `
    -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange `
    -Credential $credentials
$module = Import-PSSession $session
```

I will be receiving the recipient name from the user via read-host, parameter or pipeline, so I would like my script to bail out if the recipient is not valid and get-recipient is not successful. The -ErrorAction seemed like a logical choice for this.

```
get-recipient "doesnotexist" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; write-host "will output";
get-recipient "doesnotexist" -ErrorAction Stop; write-host "will output"
get-recipient "doesnotexist" -ErrorAction Inquire; write-host "will not output if halt selected, otherwise displayed"
```

according to get-help [about_CommonParameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh847884.aspx), -EA should modify behavior of non-terminating errors. Here I have a non-terminating error, that I would like to handle by... terminating. I know that EA is having *some* effect because I get the desired result (interactively) by setting it to "Inquire". What I would like is to terminate without interaction so I can try/catch it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-ErrorAction Stop` for this.

```
get-recipient "doesnotexist" -ErrorAction Stop; write-host "will not output"
```

Comment: This works as expected when run locally on the Exchange server. I am seeing different behavior when connecting from my workstation using New-PSSession although the error messages are identical. I will update my question with more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just troubleshooted this for the good part of 3 hours. As I was inching closer to a solution, this seemed to be a scope bug when remoting and importing Exchange sessions. I might be mistaken. However, here is a blog with a solution to it, which at the same time confirms my suspicion.

http://rehle.blogspot.dk/2014/11/exchange-remote-sessions.html .... in short, for those that would like to avoid opening the link or in case the link gets taken down:

Use the below in a script that uses Exchange cmdlets from an imported Exchange PS Session:

```
$saved=$global:ErrorActionPreference
$global:ErrorActionPreference='stop'
Try {
$box = get-mailbox nonexistent -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {
"Mailbox was not found"
}
Finally {
$global:ErrorActionPreference=$saved
}
```

I hope it helps and can help someone else. Holla :-D

Comment: Crazy that in 2024 error handling is still this inconsistent...